# Setting a QTextStream declared in header to stdout

Tags: c++, qt, stdout

I am going crazy here and I promise that I have looked at the documentation.

I declare a QTextStream as a member variable in my header file, but in my constructor, I want to set it to go to stdout in my constructor.....but I can't get the syntax right to let me do it!

All I want to do is this:

QTextStream m_text_out;

m_text_out = QTextStream(stdout)........

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an initializer list.

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();

    private:
        QTextStream m_text_out;
}

MyClass::MyClass() : m_text_out(stdout) {
}
```